# How to keep an element sticky between containers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a sticky button  inside a container, then I have an other element full width (container-fluid) but seems like the sticky only works inside it, any way to make it global?

I have tried with fixed instead of sticky but I need the behaviour that sticky gives, and also I need that website structure with a container-fluid between containers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="container" style="background-color: green;">
    <div class "row">
      <div class="col-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nibh convallis pharetra et fames orci, vestibulum dictum bibendum justo neque metus sem vivamus gravida cursus libero vehicula. Hendrerit ut per risus ac
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row sticky-top">
      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Sticky</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nibh convallis pharetra et fames orci, vestibulum dictum bibendum justo neque metus sem vivamus gravida cursus libero vehicula. Hendrerit ut per risus accumsan lacus fames himenaeos ornare turpis
        sociosqu lobortis nibh metus, interdum magna euismod odio massa tempor inceptos penatibus mollis dapibus sollicitudin. Condimentum torquent pulvinar ut semper sollicitudin imperdiet lacus quisque nunc, ante varius volutpat porttitor proin dapibus
        habitasse ornare penatibus mus, dictum habitant primis sagittis pellentesque facilisi litora fames. Non egestas vel convallis torquent leo nec nisi a, malesuada ultrices dapibus ornare mauris tortor iaculis cum commodo, facilisi fames parturient
        varius ultricies lectus taciti. Mollis vestibulum platea cum nibh aliquam ligula habitasse elementum, sociis metus litora porttitor maecenas semper quam, rutrum nam eu dapibus congue sed venenatis. Fusce senectus nascetur pulvinar ac volutpat
        mollis commodo netus arcu nisl odio ante vehicula, primis a cras aenean sagittis viverra praesent ultricies convallis per sollicitudin ultrices. Sociis auctor velit et felis a tellus dis nisi, rhoncus aliquam dui mauris sem montes mi, fermentum
        per torquent ridiculus quam justo maecenas. Placerat fusce consequat vestibulum in netus nisl condimentum curabitur suspendisse, posuere arcu volutpat ante taciti eleifend senectus tristique nunc, etiam sociosqu integer cursus nisi pharetra facilisi
        penatibus. Aliquet ad leo tincidunt ridiculus praesent mollis et faucibus, malesuada cursus conubia purus placerat condimentum felis. Massa egestas dui habitasse etiam ullamcorper eget rhoncus, ut ultrices taciti metus dis cum, eu porttitor commodo
        aliquam dictumst suscipit. Eu ultrices id varius congue mauris posuere sollicitudin lobortis convallis pellentesque praesent, sociis blandit ligula rhoncus parturient eget primis a volutpat mi, magna pulvinar molestie duis sagittis condimentum
        mus imperdiet diam et.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nibh convallis pharetra et fames orci, vestibulum dictum bibendum justo neque metus sem vivamus gravida cursus libero vehicula. Hendrerit ut per risus accumsan lacus fames himenaeos ornare turpis
        sociosqu lobortis nibh metus, interdum magna euismod odio massa tempor inceptos penatibus mollis dapibus sollicitudin. Condimentum torquent pulvinar ut semper sollicitudin imperdiet lacus quisque nunc, ante varius volutpat porttitor proin dapibus
        habitasse ornare penatibus mus, dictum habitant primis sagittis pellentesque facilisi litora fames. Non egestas vel convallis torquent leo nec nisi a, malesuada ultrices dapibus ornare mauris tortor iaculis cum commodo, facilisi fames parturient
        varius ultricies lectus taciti.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color: green;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nibh convallis pharetra et fames orci, vestibulum dictum bibendum justo neque metus sem vivamus gravida cursus libero vehicula. Hendrerit ut per risus accumsan lacus fames himenaeos ornare turpis
        sociosqu lobortis nibh metus, interdum magna euismod odio massa tempor inceptos penatibus mollis dapibus sollicitudin. Condimentum torquent pulvinar ut semper sollicitudin imperdiet lacus quisque nunc, ante varius volutpat porttitor proin dapibus
        habitasse ornare penatibus mus, dictum habitant primis sagittis pellentesque facilisi litora fames. Non egestas vel convallis torquent leo nec nisi a, malesuada ultrices dapibus ornare mauris tortor iaculis cum commodo, facilisi fames parturient
        varius ultricies lectus taciti. Mollis vestibulum platea cum nibh aliquam ligula habitasse elementum, sociis metus litora porttitor maecenas semper quam, rutrum nam eu dapibus congue sed venenatis. Fusce senectus nascetur pulvinar ac volutpat
        mollis commodo netus arcu nisl odio ante vehicula, primis a cras aenean sagittis viverra praesent ultricies convallis per sollicitudin ultrices. Sociis auctor velit et felis a tellus dis nisi, rhoncus aliquam dui mauris sem montes mi, fermentum
        per torquent ridiculus quam justo maecenas. Placerat fusce consequat vestibulum in netus nisl condimentum curabitur suspendisse, posuere arcu volutpat ante taciti eleifend senectus tristique nunc, etiam sociosqu integer cursus nisi pharetra facilisi
        penatibus. Aliquet ad leo tincidunt ridiculus praesent mollis et faucibus, malesuada cursus conubia purus placerat condimentum felis. Massa egestas dui habitasse etiam ullamcorper eget rhoncus, ut ultrices taciti metus dis cum, eu porttitor commodo
        aliquam dictumst suscipit. Eu ultrices id varius congue mauris posuere sollicitudin lobortis convallis pellentesque praesent, sociis blandit ligula rhoncus parturient eget primis a volutpat mi, magna pulvinar molestie duis sagittis condimentum
        mus imperdiet diam et.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
@endsection
```

Comment: Short answer is that it's not possible. At least not possible with pure CSS.

Sticky elements are relative to their parent container, so if you really want to stick an element inside a container so it won't scroll with the rest of the page you'll need a js solution like this https://codepen.io/angelagiese/pen/zvOvzx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below properties on `button` rather then `row` and remember don't try to override the default classes of any framework here as you see you are trying to give `sticky` position to the `row` of `bootstrap` which a **bad approach**.

```
.btn.btn-primary{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}
```

and second question it's not possible because `container fluid` and `container` are two main parent classes use in bootstrap framework inside which your structure like `row` `col` `div` exists. although you can achieve this by making your custom `class` and use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Javascript, this should be,

```
let stick = document.querySelector(".sticky-top");
let fluit = document.querySelector(".container-fluid");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
let fluitB = fluit.getBoundingClientRect();
let stickH = stick.getBoundingClientRect().height;

if(fluitB.y <= stickH) {

stick.style.position = "fixed";

} else {
stick.style.position = "sticky";
}

});
```